# How to make a macro that will transfer data to another sheet starting at a specific cell and (on subsequent invocations) work its way downwards?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a DATA INPUT cell (cell B3) in SHEET1. I want to make a macro code that when the macro button is pressed, data from cell B3 of SHEET1 will be copied to cell C5 of SHEET2 and also deleting of the data inputted in cell B3 of SHEET1. And then when I input another data and pressed the button again, the data will be copied to the next row of SHEET2, in this case cell C6. Then, cell C7, C8, and so on.

I tried to make a code for this, but I can't make it start on cell C5. It always starts from cell C2 then downwards. I tried researching codes like "Startrow", but I can't make it work.

Please see code below:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Response = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo)
If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Dim nextrow As Long
nextrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & nextrow)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you already have data in cells `C1`-`C4` on Sheet2?  `Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row+1` is basically saying “find the last row (in the column) that’s used, and then go to the next one”.  What have you done to make it think you *don’t* want it to start in Row 2?  Is it (correctly) advancing to Row 3, Row 4, Row 5, etc., when you invoke it repeatedly?

Comment: Hi Sir Scott, thank you for your reply. Yes, it is correctly advancing downwards from Row 2 to Row 3 and so on. But for my spreadsheet, I have to put data on A1:B4. So my copied/pasted data should start at Row 5, but unfortunately C1-C4 have no data. I don't know how to set VBA to start the copy/paste at C5.

Comment: Hi Sirs. I have found the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want data to be copied to Row 5 the first time the macro is run,
you could do this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Response = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo)
    If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Dim nextrow As Long
    nextrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
→→  If nextrow < 5 Then nextrow = 5                                                     ←←
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & nextrow)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have found a different answer, you should post it (***as*** a separate answer) too.