# Add data after clicking the button to next sheet and subsequently

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'd like to ask how to add, copy and display next to another sheet.
For example, I have a data in column A on rows 1 to 4 and a button named save inside sheet 1. When I enter the save button, the data in sheet 1 will copy to sheet 2 on same column and row.

When I have new data, it will add up to to row 2 from row1 under sheet2.

The data should be like this:

Sheet1

```
Name Address Age Birthdate
```

Sheet2:

```
Row1:Name   Row1:Address    Row1:Age    Row1: Birth date;
Row2:Name   Row2:Address    Row2:Age    Row2: Birth date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As you demanded I've set the Row 2 of Sheet 1 as Data Entry Row, every time you need to write data in Row 2 and Excel will add new record into Sheet 2 after existing record.*

*Then after Excel will Delete the new record from Row 2 in Sheet 1 and place the Cell Pointer on Cell A2, so that you can write new record.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
   Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
     Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

       copySheet.range("A2:D2").Copy
       pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

        xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False

      Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
    Range("A2").Select

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**NB:** In this sample code I've used Row 2 for Data Entry, if you feel you can 
        alter it.

Comment: Hi Rajesh...wow....great codes. it really works.....thank you sooooo much....more power to you.

Comment: Nice to hear from you, and happy to learn that you got the solution. Now is your tern to vote it as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you a very simple bunch of VBA codes.

It will copy every new row from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 whenever you click the Command button.

*Also, first copy the Row headings in both sheets then write New record & finally Click Command button.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

       range([A2], ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

           Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**NB:** In my sample code the Source Cell is A2, you can pick the Cell of your choice.

Comment: Format your code by selecting all of it and then click the "Code" icon in the menu bar.  It looks like this:  {}

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thank you. I really much appreciate your codes.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thank you. I really much appreciate your codes. I tried it and it works. A little that i kinda want. The code you have is in the first step. however, if i have new name such as Y in sheet 1 in same row, the name Y should display to the next row in sheet 2. It's kinda more like sheet 1 is data entry. sheet 2 is like data server that saved from data encoded in sheet 1. Thanks in advance. I'm also trying in here. Anyways, great code! Thanks :)

Comment: Row 2  is like the data entry in sheet 1. The rows in sheet 2 should be like the receiver of the data where it saved. If i have a data that i type in row2 in sheet1, the data should displayed in row2. if i have a new data i type in row 2 in sheet1, the data should be diplayed in row3. if i have another new data i type in row2 in sheet1, another data in row4 in sheet2 should displayed.

Comment: @E.G,, nice  to hear from you since  you found the code working & useful for you then Click it as  ANSWER.

Comment: @E.G, if you are looking for Data Entry Form, Excel does have just activate it, should be the most convenient for you.

Comment: i find more convenient  using excel cell than data entry forms Rajesh. your code works but want to find more codes to execute.

Comment: i am right now trying to expand using your code. just want to find the answer code how to copy the cell value from sheet 1 on a same row into sheet 2 using different rows. it is kinda you input like 5 Names in one row and it will save in another sheet and in 5 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Hi looks like i found the answer codes.

i'd like to share.

```
Dim nextrow As Long
nextrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If nextrow < 3 Then nextrow = 3

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & nextrow)
```

also herewith is the link path.
[How to make a macro that will transfer data to another sheet starting at a specific cell and (on subsequent invocations) work its way downwards?](https://superuser.com/questions/1243234/how-to-make-a-macro-that-will-transfer-data-to-another-sheet-starting-at-a-speci?rq=1)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of my queries...this is the answer from @Rajesh. Thanks!

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
   Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

```
Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

   copySheet.range("A2:D2").Copy
   pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

    xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

  Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
Range("A2").Select
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub