# Excel data entry without user forms

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using excel 2016 for Mac and it does not support user forms. 
What I want to accomplish is to add new entries to my table (rows) using some kind of input field so that you can only add new entries trough this input field and cannot freely modify the sheet. 
Does anyone have an idea how I can do that without user forms?

UPDATE: I could use the first row to get user data. How would my VBA script look like to take the data at the first row and append it to end of the sheet?

Here is a screenshot of what I thought could work:

[image]

Comment: For part 2 (cannot freely modify the sheet) [Cell protection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-cells-to-protect-them-in-Excel-2016-for-Mac-59BB04CF-1A79-4A69-9828-568C98BDB310) is your friend

Comment: Since I've never used MAC version of Excel, but I'm sure that it has also built-in Data Form. You can use it for data entry as well as modifications and deletions too. If not finding in Ribbon Tab, you can add it to Quick Access Tool-bar, Add More Commands.

Comment: Depending on kind of information you will be looking for users to input, you can use a number of tools in Excel (Data Validation, Dropdown lists, etc.)  If you can be more specific, we can give you better answers.  As mcalex mentioned, you can protect the rest of the worksheet where users will not be entering data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be to use Data Validation.

Highlight the cells where the users will be entering data.

Go to the Data tab.  In the Data tab ribbon, click on Data Validation.

This will bring up a dialog box where you can customize and limit the data type users can enter.

As for part 2. you can protect the worksheet by going to the Review tab.  On the ribbon for the Review tab, there are a number of options to protect the Sheet, Workbook  etc.  If you click on these icons, it will similarly allow you to customize the kind of protection you want for your workbook/worksheet.

These are both available in Excel 2016 for Mac (as well as Excel for Windows).  I just checked.

Run this macro after you have entered the data and it will append the data to the end.

Sub EnterAtEnd()

```
Dim LastRow As Long, Rng As Range

Range("D1:F1").Select
Selection.Copy
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With
Set Rng = Range("D" & LastRow)
Rng.Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

Note: D1:F1 is the area where the new data is entered.  Column D is the first column of the data you are collecting

You can create a button to push after you have entered the data to run this macro.

Comment: Thanks. I get it that I can validate the content of the cell with Data validation but how can i make that entry be appended at the end of the table? (I added a screenshot to the question)

Comment: Marcello S.  I added some visual basic code that might help you add the row to the last row of data.  You will have to adjust the code to the range and columns of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you one most easiest solution recently I've had posted here only. Just Click this link.*

[Add data after clicking the button to next sheet and subsequently](https://superuser.com/questions/1277058/add-data-after-clicking-the-button-to-next-sheet-and-subsequently)

Check the VBA Code which has been voted as Answer.

**NB:** That Solution is between 2 Sheets, you can perform it in one Sheet also, change Copy & Paste Data Range and Sheet Name as your need.

*Hope this help you.*